# ES6 class in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have a angularjs project, and I'm writing in Es6, and I made a class like this.

```
class DateTimeConverter {
constructor() {
    this.format = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss';
    this.customerTz = 'Asia/Tokyo';
}

static convertToUtc(date) {
    date = moment.tz(date, this.customerTz);
    date = date.clone().tz('UTC');
    date = date.format(this.format);

    return date;
}
}
```

But I can't get it to work in my code.

In my controller I'm trying to do this.

```
$scope.form.from = DateTimeConverter.convertToUTC($scope.form.from);
```

But it tells me DateTimeConverter is not defined

How do I go about using this class in my code?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to import the DateTimeConverter class as below

```
import { DateTimeConverter } from './DateTimeConverter';
```

*./DateTimeConverter*- File path

For detail ref  [import statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript names are case sensitive:

```
//$scope.form.from = DateTimeConverter.convertToUTC($scope.form.from);    

$scope.form.from = DateTimeConverter.convertToUtc($scope.form.from);
```